# How can I disable associating changes and work items in a TFS 2015 build?

Tags: xaml, tfs

In my TFS and VS2013 xaml builds, I could conditionally call the activity

> AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems

based on a custom flag set at queue time.  I'm attempting to convert my (heavily customized) xaml builds to the new build system but my changes are always associated.  I haven't been able to find a flag or other way to conditionally disable it.

Is there a way to conditionally disable associating changes and work items to a build with the new TFS 2015 build system?  Hopefully, I'm just missing something simple.

Comment: There is no such setting in TFS 2015 new build system by default. Could you let us know why do you want to disable AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT  Thank you for your response.  One use case of this feature is to be able to launch a build just to test code changes but don't associate anything yet.  I know I can work around this by creating and maintaining a second build definition but I'd rather be able to control the association step like I can in xaml builds.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such setting in TFS 2015 new build system by default. I have submitted a UserVoice at website below, you can vote it, Product Team will evaluate it carefully:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/16720096-add-settings-of-disable-associatechangesetsandwork

Comment: Thank you.  In the mean time, I will go back to using VS2013 to create and maintain xaml builds.